# python, show values on a heatmap tooltip

Tags: python, data-visualization, heatmap

I have a heatmap, created by pyplot.pcolor.
When I move the cursor on the cells, I get the info of the x,y. How can I see the cell value as well?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you can have a look at this: https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor